# Cannot resolve an error" Error reading the C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\ directory." while executing ASP.NET Core web app

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core web application. The project is built successfully but I keep getting this unhandled exception

> Error reading the C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\ directory.

The app runs alright but this error pops up every time I run the application. How to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you are looking at this issue due to software conflicts. If you have a third-party antivirus software installed on your computer, kindly uninstall it first. Third-party antivirus software can cause issues like this. To be sure, you can perform a clean boot on your computer [(Link)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. I don't have any third-party antivirus installed on my system. This makes it more confusing.

Comment: @PallabiGuha Maybe .Net Framework is damaged. To help resolve the issue, I suggest repairing the framework by following the steps in this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2698555/microsoft--net-framework-repair-tool-is-available to help in resolving the issue. You can also download the ```Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool```https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

Comment: hi. It says the tool is unable to fix the installation issues on your computer. Any other workaround? I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything yet this error keeps popping up.

Comment: @PallabiGuha https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-net-framework-repair-tool-unable-to/57d4a5a3-dc54-4489-9044-ae8a5ada0fde  please read this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. So, I fixed it like this:

1. Uninstall IIS 10.0 (in my case) Express using Apps & features
2. Download IIS 10.0 Express manually from [msdn](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264) and install it
3. Clean Solution

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. I went to the iisexppress folder in Temp and it tells me that "You don't current have permission to access this folder".

I then ran Visual Studio as administrator and the error doesn't appear. So it's a permissions problem for me, and I don't know why it happens...!

I then went to my Temp folder and renamed iisexpress to issexpress.bak. Then reloaded visual studio (not as admin) and ran and it didn't show this error message, as it recreated the iisexpress folder with the right permissions this time.